# Passing a variable into a filter with typescript in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, filtering, angular-datatables

I want to be able to filter based on user selection. If I hard code in the filter it works but when I try to use 'selectSeachColumn' as a variable in the filter I get the error message: "Cannot read property 'selectSeachColumn' of undefined", whether I hard code the variable as below or connect it to the select.

This is what I have so far:

HTML (I'm using the custom pipe "keys":

The select input:

```
<md-select placeholder="Search in..." [(ngModel)]="selectSeachColumn">
  <md-option *ngFor="let col of tableColumnNames | keys" [value]="col.key">
    {{ col.value }}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

The table:

```
      <input
        type='text'
        style='padding:8px;margin:15px auto;width:30%;'
        placeholder='Type to filter the name column...'
        (keyup)='updateFilter($event)'
      />
      <ngx-datatable
        #table
        class='material'
        [columns]="columns"
        [columnMode]="'force'"
        [headerHeight]="50"
        [footerHeight]="50"
        [rowHeight]="'auto'"
        [limit]="5"
        [rows]='rows'>
      </ngx-datatable>
```

TS:

```
selectSeachColumn = 'purchaseOrder';

  updateFilter(event) {
  const val = event.target.value;

  this.temp = [...this.rows];

  const temp = this.temp.filter(function(d) {
    return d.selectSeachColumn.indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
  });

  // update the rows
  this.rows = temp;

  // Whenever the filter changes, always go back to the first page
  this.table.offset = 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(d)` print inside the `filter` function before the `return` statement?

Comment: If I hard-code in "purchaseOrder" then I get all the Objects of the rows that should come up. If I try to use the variable selectSeachColumn then I just get one Object. I don't really understand why.